# Interface cannot be cast to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, classcastexception

I have created a separate class for the background process. In that, I have two classes and an interface. I am getting string data from the first class and then based on that data I am getting a list of data in another class. The whole process is working fine but now I want to send that list to my fragment but getting `java.lang.ClassCastException`

below is my code:-

```
public class PlacesTaskNew extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;

    public PlacesTaskNew(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {

        String data = "";
        -- --
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask(context);
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {

        String data = "";
        -- --
        return data;
    }

    public interface PlaceTaskInterface {
        void onGetPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> result, String[] from, int[] to);
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;
        Context mContext;
        PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface;

        public ParserTask(Context mContext) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.placeTaskInterface = (PlaceTaskInterface) mContext;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            --  --
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[]{"description"};
            int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
            placeTaskInterface.onGetPlaces(result, from, to);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my Fragment class :-

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements PlaceTaskInterface {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Locality.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                //here is the error
                placesTaskNew = new PlacesTaskNew(getActivity());
                placesTaskNew.execute(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        PlacesTaskNew placesTaskNew = new PlacesTaskNew(getActivity());
        placesTaskNew.execute(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> result, String[] from, int[] to) {
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
        Locality.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Below is the logcat error :-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.theweedconnect.me, PID: 14807
java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to PlaceTaskInterface
```

Please help, Thanx :)

Comment: May I have your `SimpleAdapter ` code please?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanx to @ρяσѕρєя K, here is what I suggest

Add `PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface` in both constructors

**PlacesTaskNew construcor**

```
Context context;
PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface;

public PlacesTaskNew(Context context, PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.placeTaskInterface = placeTaskInterface;
}
```

write these lines in `onPostExecute` method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask(context, this.placeTaskInterface);
    parserTask.execute(result);
}
```

**ParserTask Constructor**

```
JSONObject jObject;
Context mContext;
PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface;

public ParserTask(Context mContext, PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.placeTaskInterface = placeTaskInterface;
}
```

And finally in your `Fragment`, write as belows

```
Locality.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        placesTaskNew = new PlacesTaskNew(getActivity(), new PlacesTaskNew.PlaceTaskInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onGetPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> result, String[] from, int[] to) {
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
                Locality.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        placesTaskNew.execute(charSequence.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
});
```

Regards!

Answer (score 7):

`PlaceTaskInterface` is implemented in `Fragment` (DashboardFragment) instead of `Activity` which is return by `getActivity()` method.

Pass `this` as second parameter to `PlacesTaskNew` class constructor to get interface instance :

```
PlacesTaskNew placesTaskNew = new PlacesTaskNew(getActivity(),this);
```

Comment: Can you provide me constructor code, There are two constructor in the class

Comment: @Sid: Use `public ParserTask(Context mContext,PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.placeTaskInterface = placeTaskInterface;
        }`

Comment: But I am calling `ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask(context, this);` in the same class then what should I pass in place of `PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface`

Comment: @Sid: Nothing  when creating object just pass `this`

Comment: It is saying `ParserTask(Context, PlaceTaskInterface)` can not be applied to `ParserTask(Context, ParserTaskNew)`  :(

Comment: @Sid: Why you are passing `ParserTaskNew` ?? when defined `constructor` is as `public ParserTask(Context mContext,PlaceTaskInterface placeTaskInterface){...}` ?

Comment: @Sid: Very easy steps : 1. add second parameter of type `PlaceTaskInterface` in `ParserTask` class constructor, 2. pass `this` as second parameter when creating object of `ParserTask` class from `Fragment`. 3. DONE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132357/discussion-between--k-and-sid).

Comment: I am not passing it i just write there `this`. Please see my `PlacesTaskNew` full code and tell me how to apply